# (WPF) How to set FocusVisualStyle for ListViewItem when ListView uses Views

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have a ListView control that uses Views like View="{StaticResource SmallIcons}"

The SmallIcons view has the following structure:

```
<local:TileView x:Key="SmallIcons" SelectedBackground="{DynamicResource SlctnBrsh}"  CornerRadius="3" SelectedBorderBrush="LightGreen" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SmallIconsDT}"/>
```

and the SmallIconsDT is a dataTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SmallIconsDT" >
.........
</DataTemplate>
```

And I have a FocusVisualStyle  as following:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisualStyle1"  TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="#FFFF9900" Background="#3F000000"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How to set this FocusVisualStyle1 to this ListView items?

I don't have experience for this case. I know that FocusVisualStyle needs ControlTemplate to be set. But I use DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` is an `ItemsControl` and an `ItemsControl` uses a container element for each item (for `ListView` this will be `ListViewItem`).
You have to change the `FocusVisualStyle` of that container element.

This can easily be done by using the [`ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2) property

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisualStyle1}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListView>
```